# Handing reset in SystemVerilog assertions

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

How are the following two properties different?

```
property p1;
    @(posedge clk) disable iff (Reset) b ##1 c;
endproperty

property p2;
    @(posedge clk) (~Reset & b) ##1 c;
endproperty

assert property (p1);
assert property (p2);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very different.

In `p1`, `Reset` is asynchronous not sampled. At any time during the evaluation of `p1`, `Reset` becomes true, the property is disabled. While Reset is false, there is an attempt at every `posedge clock` to check that `b` is be true followed one clock cycle later, `c` is true for the attempt to pass, otherwise it fails. If at any time Reset becomes true, all active attempts are killed off.

In `p2`, `Reset` is synchronously sampled. There is an attempt at every `posedge clock` to check that `~Reset &b` is be true followed one clock cycle later, `c` is true for the attempt to pass, otherwise it fails. The attempt will fail if `Reset` becomes true.

Answer (score 1):

- `p1` has an asynchronous reset. At any port `Reset` is high any active `p1` threads are aborted.
- `p2` only check `Reset` at the first clock. The assertion fails if `Reset==1` or `b==0`.

Here are are two examples of ways to visual it.

```
clk   ‾‾‾\__/‾‾‾\__/‾‾‾
Reset _________/‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
b     ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
c     ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾\_______ c is asynchronously reset by Reset in this example
p1          .___        Assertion aborts on posedge Reset
p2          .______↓    Assertion fails
```

```
clk   ‾‾‾\__/‾‾‾\__/‾‾‾
Reset ____/‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
b     ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾\_________
c     ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
p1                      Assertion never starts
p2          ↓      ↓    Assertion fails
```